# how to get the count of the in the reverse order?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

How do i get the count in the reverse order? Right now, i have displayed the number of count's done.. But i also want the number of counts left. And how do i reset the timer at end of each day in the below program and display the last time it was executed? Could someone help me with the whole program?
The program is -

```
namespace Time_Writer
{
  class Program
  {
    static int count = 1;
    static double seconds;
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReadCountFromFile();


        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed +=new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(aTimer_Elapsed);
        aTimer.Interval = 5000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Exit The Program\n");
        Console.ReadLine();


        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit);


    }
    private static void ReadCountFromFile()
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(".\\mynumber.dat"))
            {
                using (var file = File.Open(".\\mynumber.dat", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
                    file.Read(bytes, 0, 4);
                    count = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("Limit = 10000");
                    Console.WriteLine("Count  = {0}", count);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Problem reading file.");
        }
    }
    static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var file = File.Open(".\\mynumber.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            var buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(count);
            file.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
    private static void aTimer_Elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name is Yap {0}", e.SignalTime);
        seconds += 5;
        count += 1;
        if (count>10000 || seconds==86400)
        {
            aTimer.Enabled = false;
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nTimer is off at {0}\n\n", e.SignalTime.TimeOfDay.ToString());
        }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain what your program is supposed to do? Why does it write to a file? What is it reading?

Comment: @gideon I dont think the whole code posted here does not required to his question.

Comment: @gideon Actually this program is to repeat the given statement 10k times a day.. Instead of the statement, i can insert mails and send it to different recipients. It writes to a file because I need to keep a count of the mails sent and mails remaining. Could u help me?

Comment: @Jayanga so what? i just posted it so that people could actually see what the program is about n then get a clue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
Console.WriteLine("Limit = 10000");
Console.WriteLine("Count: {0} of 10000. {1} remaining", count, 10000 - count);
```

Comment: Hey Yeah.. Thanks alot :) But how do i save the "date and time" the last time it was executed and display it everytime it is executed freshly with previous dates n time.. hope u understood what i meant..